# Request header was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-web-api2

In my API, I have the following code:

```
public class CustomOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{

    public override Task MatchEndpoint(OAuthMatchEndpointContext context)
    {
        if (context.OwinContext.Request.Method == "OPTIONS" && context.IsTokenEndpoint)
        {
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", new[] { "POST" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
                new[] { 
                    "access-control-allow-origin", 
                    "accept", 
                    "x-api-applicationid", 
                    "content-type", 
                    "authorization" 
                });
            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
            context.OwinContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;

            context.RequestCompleted();

            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }

        return base.MatchEndpoint(context);
    }

    // ... even more code, but not relevant

}
```

When I connect to this API from Chrome, everything works perfect. When I connect from the same computer to the same API, but only from a different browser, Internet Explorer 11, I get the following error:

> SEC7123: Request header x-api-applicationid was not present in the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.

I debugged the code, and I see the headers are added to the response. Even IE shows the headers:

[image: IE11 response]

What does IE expect?

**Update**

If I change the order of the headers from

```
new[] { 
    "access-control-allow-origin", 
    "accept", 
    "x-api-applicationid", 
    "content-type", 
    "authorization" 
}
```

to:

```
new[] { 
    "content-type",
    "accept",
    "access-control-allow-origin",
    "x-api-applicationid", 
    "authorization" 
}
```

The error message changes to:

> SEC7123: Request header **access-control-allow-origin** was not present in the
>   Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.

So it always gives an error on the third header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a piece of code [here](http://blog.rfaisal.com/2014/01/14/building-your-own-api-and-securing-it-with-oauth-2-0-in-asp-net-webapi-2/) which fixed it for me.

```
//Startup.cs
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        IOwinRequest req = context.Request;
        IOwinResponse res = context.Response;
        if (req.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/oauth2/token")))
        {
            var origin = req.Headers.Get("Origin");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(origin))
            {
                res.Headers.Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
            }
            if (req.Method == "OPTIONS")
            {
                res.StatusCode = 200;
                res.Headers.AppendCommaSeparatedValues("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET", "POST");
                res.Headers.AppendCommaSeparatedValues("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "authorization", "content-type", "x-api-applicationid", "access-control-allow-origin");
                return;
            }
        }
        await next();
    });

    // rest of owin Oauth config
}
```

I removed the `MatchEndpoint` method from my CustomOAuthProvider.cs

Answer (score 6):

Make sure it's not as simple as a misspelling of the content-type header in your AJAX. I was getting this with an OPTIONS preflight with an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type, which doesn't necessitate a preflight, but I had

`content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

instead of

`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

as my `contentType` option.

WRONG:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/api/Account/Token',
    contentType: 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        grant_type: "password",
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    },
});
```

RIGHT:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/api/Account/Token',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {
        grant_type: "password",
        username: $('#username').val(),
        password: $('#password').val()
    },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to remove `MatchEndPoint`

Instead of adding array element just add Comma-Separated value as first array element in **Access-Control-Allow-Headers**

Instead of

```
 context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
                new[] { 
                    "access-control-allow-origin", 
                    "accept", 
                    "x-api-applicationid", 
                    "content-type", 
                    "authorization" 
                });
```

use

```
context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 
    new[] { 
        "access-control-allow-origin,accept,x-api-applicationid,content-type,authorization" 
    });
```