# SEC7123: Request header Key was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, cors, microsoft-edge

I am trying to pass a custom header to my Web API from an angular HTTP Interceptor.
I have added the header in the list of allowed headers in the web.config as

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Key,Content-Type" />
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

This is working fine in Chome but in Microsoft edge it gives me the following error:

```
SEC7123: Request header Key was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.
```

Is there any other setting that I am missing?

Comment: similar question that may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168061/request-header-was-not-present-in-the-access-control-allow-headers-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding the below code in the BeginRequest method in Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest (Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains ("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS") 
    {
        Context.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Key, Accept,Authorization,serverName");
        Context.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        Context.Response.End ();
    }
}
```