# How to use Bitly V4 URL Shorten API on IE11

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11, request-headers, preflight

I am trying to use the Bitly V4 URL Shorten API on IE11 via ajax POST, but getting security error after the preflight (OPTIONS) call. My implementation and error encountered as below:

#### My code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v4/shorten',
    data: JSON.stringify({group_guid: '<Bitly_group_guid>', long_url: 'https://www.google.com'}),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer <Bitly_generic_access_token>',
    },
}).done(function (resp) {
    console.log('OK');
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('NOT OK');
});
```

#### Error in IE11 console (thrown after the preflight):

> SEC7123: Request header content-type was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.
>
> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.

#### Preflight (OPTIONS) Response Header - response code 200:

> access-control-allow-headers: *
>
> access-control-allow-methods: HEAD, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
>
> access-control-allow-origin: *
>
> allow: POST, OPTIONS
>
> alt-svc: clear
>
> content-length: 0
>
> content-security-policy: default-src 'none
>
> date: Thu, 28 Nov 2019 03:13:04 GMT
>
> server: nginx
>
> strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>
> via: 1.1 google
>
> x-content-type-options: nosniff
>
> x-frame-options: DENY
>
> x-xss-protection: 1; mode=blockFilter

In the end the POST method doesn't execute at all, **the same code however WORKING on Chrome and Mozilla, which the POST method get executed and managed to shorten the URL**.

- I have a read on [Bitly CORS](https://dev.bitly.com/cors.html), but it doesn't seems to support V4 from my understanding.
- I can't opt to make change to Internet settings on local machine as the same need to be done by every end user.

Appreciate if anyone can share insights to overcome this.

Comment: I try to check the documentation and there are no any specific steps mentioned for IE browser. I tested the above code but I am getting 403 error in all browsers. I searched about that error and this thread can be helpful for fixing that error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27168061/request-header-was-not-present-in-the-access-control-allow-headers-list For testing purpose, try to test with lower security settings. I will also try to discuss the issue with other engineers to take their suggestions on this issue. Thanks for your understanding,

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Thanks for your feedback. I have edited the code snippet with corrected syntax and valid sample value, it should be OK to test with now combining with valid Bitly's param. For testing purpose I enabled the "Access data sources across domains" in Internet Options, it works fine. I have also check the link you shared, unfortunately the changes to be done is on the host end itself, which is different from my use case where implementation is on client side to call Bitly's API.

Comment: Do you mean after enabling the "Access data sources across domains" option it starts working with IE browser? I again tested your updated code but it shows the same 403 error on my side.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, yes it started to work after enabling the "Access data sources across domians". The code should work, have you tried to replace the Bitly params accordingly?

Comment: Thanks for letting us know about it that enabling the "Access data sources across domians" option solved the issue. I suggest you to post your solution as an answer and  try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT, although enabling the "Access data sources across domians" option solved the issue, it's not feasible to ask every end user of the website to perform same, hence I will not regard this as an accepted answer for my use case, meanwhile I like to accept yours answer as accepted, at least that is some fact which I can bring out for further discussion with the team. Lastly, Thanks for your support to really help on the question and being kind enough for not nitpicking on the red tape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the documentation I found this information about browser support for Bitly api.

> The Bitly web app supports the latest versions of Chrome, Firefox,
>   Edge, and Safari. We recommend using one of these browsers for full
>   functionality of the web app.
>
> Other browsers are not tested and may not function properly with the
>   Bitly web app.

Reference:

[Which browsers does the Bitly web app support?](https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036286231-Which-browsers-does-the-Bitly-web-app-support-)

Comment: Thanks, guess this is the best response I can have for now. Btw, I've submitted the same inquiry to Bitly's forum in Google Group, unfortunately the group seems to be inactive for quite some time @ [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bitly-api)